# Вопрос по react

Tags: reactjs

в процессе изучения React возник вопрос. Стоит ли добавлять React на сайт, если нужно добавить небольшой скрипт(к примеру лендинг) или можно обойтись обычным jQuery?

Comment: Можно вполне обойтись и без React, и без jQuery. В отдельных случаях можно обойтись без скриптов вообще

Comment: Реакт полезен там где есть много переиспользуемых компонент либо сложная система вложенности с обновлением данных для отображения, в простый случаях я полностью согласен с @andreymal

Comment: Как упоминали в комментариях можно обойтись и без React, если нужно применить маленький скрипт на сайте не стоит для этого использовать React, наоборот могут возникнуть проблемы с оптимизацией